# django navlink not working when i click on the nav menu item.how to solve this?

Tags: django-views, django-templates, navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TaskMate</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href=" {% url 'todolist' %} ">Todo List</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href=" {% url 'contact' % } ">Contact US</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href=" {% url 'about' % } ">About US</a>

</div>
```

//urls.py

urlpatterns = [
path('',views.todolist,name='todolist'),

```
path('contact',views.contact,name='contact'),

path('about',views.about,name='about'),
```

]